# Show that is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. Show that $[x_1,x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3,x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4]$ is also a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

How do I show that they are linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^4$? What could be an approach for solving this problem. Thanks

Comment: I have added LaTeX to your question. Please see that the edit is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there's a linear combination that makes $0$; then there are constants $c_i$ such that

$$c_1 x_1 + c_2 (x_1 + x_2) + c_3 (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) + c_4 (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4) = 0$$

Rearrange this to get

$$(c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4) x_1 + (c_2 + c_3 + c_4) x_2 + (c_3 + c_4) x_3 + c_4 x_4 = 0$$

Now determine what each $c_i$ is, starting with $c_4$.

To show that it spans, try writing the standard basis vectors as a linear combination of the new basis.

Comment: So in this case C1 = C2 = C3 = C4 = 0. This must be true in order to be linearly independent?

Comment: @user109863 Yes. That's the definition of linear independence.